# docker-compose script with prompt…. better solution?

Tags: bash, docker, docker-compose

I have a **bash script** to start various docker-compose.yml(s)

One of these compose instances is docker-compose.password.yml to create a password file for mysql. For that I need to prompt the user to input a user name and then run a service in docker (that is actually not running).

basically the only way I can think of to accomplish this is run the docker in idle state, exec the command and close the docker. Is there a better way?

(easier would be to do it directly with docker run, but then I would have to check if the image is already available and have image definitions in the various docker-compose.ymls plus now also in the bash script)

XXXXXXXXXX
My solution:

docker-compose.password.yml

```
version: '2'
services:
  createpw:
    command:
      top -b -d 3600
```

then

```
docker-compose -f docker-compose.password.yml up -d
```

prompt the user by my bash script outside of docker for the credentials

```
read -p "Input user name.echo $’\n> ’" username
```

and send it to the running docker

```
docker exec createpw /bin/bash -c "mysql_config_editor set --user=${username} --password"
```

and then `docker-compose down`

xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx

Tried and not working:
I tried to have just a small subscript prompting for the input right under command

```
command:
  /bin/bash /somewhere/createpassword.sh
```

This did produce the file, but the user was an empty string, as the prompt didn’t stop the docker execution. It didn’t matter if I used compose -d or not.

Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks.

Comment: you bash script to start .yml could be the one that prompt for password, and that password is then inserted to .env file or to `docker run -e` ...

Comment: that is what I meant with "do it directly with docker run, but then I would have to check if the image is already available". in other words I would need to add an additional check for the image itself